# which kind of array can give to paste0

Tags: r, paste

I wana a type (an array) that can be input for paste0 and then result be concatenate of elements of that type.
something like this:

```
x=c("a","b")
paste0(x)
#result be: ab
```

Comment: Your example isn't an array, it's a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly what you're looking for but you can just use `Reduce` to concatenate an array with `paste0`

```
x=c("a","b")
Reduce(paste0,x)
# [1] "ab"
```

Comment: `paste0(x, collapse="")`